# Mock a function by replacing it with a dummy alternative

Tags: javascript, testing, mocking, sinon, stub

I have a async function I'd like to monitor if it's being called and what the arguments are. The function takes in two arguments makes a network request and comes back with a response based on the two arguments, for instance let's say it's an addition api. You pass in `1` and `1` and get `2`. Rather then making this request I'd like to create a mock for it where I replace this method with it's syncronously counterpart. For instance.

Here's the original add function:

```
const async realAdd = (a, b) => {
    return makeRequest(`http://my-service.com/add?a=${a}&b=${b}`)
}
```

Here's the one I'd like to use for mocking:

```
const async dummyAdd = (a, b) => {
    return Promise.resolve(a + b)
}
```

Let's say there is a function that takes `add` and uses it. In this case this is function I'd like to use, and I'd like to mock `add` with the previous version.

```
const mockAdd = sinon.something(dummyAdd)
let result = someFunctionThatUses(mockAdd)
assert.equal(mockAdd.called, 1)
```

All I want is a way to pass in the dummy `add` method and check if it's been called, but I still want the `add` function to `return` the promise.

Answer (score 0):

```
const spy = sinon.spy(mockAdd);
let result = someFunctionThatUses(mockAdd);
assert(spy.calledOnce);
```

---

Documentation Reference: http://sinonjs.org/releases/v4.1.1/spies/